# The Term Get-SPOWebs is not recognized as name of cmdlet

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Assuming Connect-SPOService is connected successfully. Why am I getting error for Get-SPOWebs error. I am trying to get subsite of sposite but getting this error.

```
function get-siteCollections{

#Get all site collections

$siteCollections = Get-SPOSite

#loop through all site collections

foreach ($siteCollection in $siteCollections)

{

#set variable for a tab in the table

$pixelsweb = 0

$pixelslist = 0

#add info to HTML document

add-content -value "<tr style='background-color:cyan'><td>$($siteCollection.url)</td><td>TopSite</td><td>$($sitecollection.template)</td><td></td></tr>" -path $filePath

write-host "Info: Found $($siteCollection.url)" -foregroundcolor green

#search for webs

$AllWebs = Get-SPOWebs($siteCollection.url)
Write-Host $AllWebs

}

get-sitecollections
```

Answer (score 1):

`Get-SPOWebs` is not the built-in function. You need to define it like this:

[Powershell to list all sites and subsites in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/101263/75974)