# How many maximum number of sites will be returned from GetSitePropertiesFromSharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I can find a number of articles on how to get all sites in SharePoint online and everyone referring to the below method

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt779503(v%3Doffice.15)

One of the answers I am looking for is how many maximum number of sites will it return?

My gut feeling says it will not return all and there has to be a specific number.

When I looked at properties of "SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable" object I can see "NextStartIndex" which clearly for next  number of sites.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/dn159183%28v%3doffice.15%29

Hope someone can help me here

**Edit(2/9)**
Based on below blog post it should only return 200 sites

https://briantjackett.com/2017/08/23/sharepoint-csom-to-traverse-all-sites-in-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possibilities how get **all SPO sites**:

- in PowerShell with SPO cmds: `Get-SPOSite -Limit All` documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps), now listing Groups and Teams sites too. Great article is [written here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101176/powershell-to-list-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online).
- with [PNP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnptenantsite?view=sharepoint-ps) `Get-PnPTenantSite` after `Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://company-admin.sharepoint.com`

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for an answer on how many maximum number items will "GetSitePropertiesFromSharePoint" api return.

Comment: Ah ok, so you can try it and you will see? I havent find any documentation for it.

Comment: Not sure how many sites should I create one of the blog posts says it's going to return max 200 but not sure so looking for some concrete answers. Preferably from Microsoft site.