# Getting all SharePoint sites from root directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site-collection, root

So I am new SharePoint online administrator and working at a small company. I got a task to move my company into SharePoint which before were used minimaly without much of administration.

Today I found out that there is at least a few sites that is in root directory. As most sites are `https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName`, these are in https://companyname.sharepoint.com/SiteName. I currently trying to get a list of these sites to prepare a plan on how to deal with them, I tried using `Get-SPOSite` in sharepoint, but showed only sites that I can see in admin panel as well.

Comment: refer this link, it has powershell approach, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101176/powershell-to-list-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried this approach already, but it returns only sites that are in sharepoint.com/sites/ location while sites ub sharepoint.com/ doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this using the [PNPPowerShel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
  #Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://teanat-admin.sharepoint.com -Credentials $Cred

$allsites = Get-PnPTenantSite

foreach($site in $allsites)
{
    Try {
        #Connect to PNP Online
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.url -Credentials $Cred
 
        #Get subsites in SharePoint Online using PnP PowerShell
        $WebsCollection = Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse
 
        ForEach($Web in $WebsCollection)
        {
            Write-host "Site Collection URL =" $site.Url " has this subwebs =" $Web.Url
        }
        }
    catch {
        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
        }
}
```

Disconnect-PnPOnline

## Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/powershell-to-get-all-subsites-in-sitecollection-sharepoint-online.html#ixzz67o162L6J