# Get a list of Pages and Subpages of the SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site, reports

Is it possible to get a list of all the pages and subpages of a particular SharePoint site? Also is this doable in an Excel type report? I distinctly remember there was a map in the older version of SharePoint which had branches of all it's pages and subpages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pages, you can use powershell script to export a csv file of all pages. Here is an example you can use:http://blog.tofte-it.dk/powershell-get-all-sharepoint-pages-in-a-site-collection/

And it seems you are acutually looking for a way to get all sub sites in a site collecton, here is an example powershell script you can refer to:[Powershell to list all sites and subsites in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101176/powershell-to-list-all-sites-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-online)
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-all-collections-and-be30148a/view/Discussions#content

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your view to datasheet under your Site Pages. Then limit the columns to the information you want. Under Item Limit set your limit to include all the pages. Then cut and paste special - text into excel.

You end up with an extra line for every page (Select or deselect this item) but you just need to sort the information and delete that extra line.